# Maximum Value + Select Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with the following JSFiddle.

I basically want to highlight the div with the highest value with a yellow border.

However, if multiple divs have the same value which is the max, the program must choose a div randomly out of all the divs with the max value.

For example, one of the three divs with 20 should be randomly selected and it's border-color should be yellow.

http://jsfiddle.net/DyGqm/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="num">16</div>
<div class="num">20</div>
<div class="num">18</div>
<div class="num">20</div>
<div class="num">20</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.num {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;    
}​
```

**JS**

```
var max = -Infinity;

var maxEle = $(".num").each(function() {
    if (+this.value > max) max = +this.value;
}).filter(function() {
    return this.value == max;
});

if (maxEle.length > 1) maxEle = maxEle.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxEle.length));

maxEle.css("border-color", "yellow");​
```

Comment: Your code doesn't highlight the div with max value(one or more)? right?

Comment: Well my code is supposed to but it doesn't work. It is supposed to change the border color to yellow (highlight) of the div with the max value

Comment: Also have a look at [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 5):

1) You haven't selected jQuery as the framework. It's using MooTools.

2) `div`s don't have `.value`. You can use `.innerHTML`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DyGqm/8/

Final code:

```
var max = -Infinity;

var maxEle = $(".num").each(function() {
    if (+this.innerHTML > max) max = +this.innerHTML;
}).filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML == max;
});


if (maxEle.length > 1) maxEle = maxEle.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxEle.length));

maxEle.css("border-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Oops I think I might have selected MooTools by mistake lol. Oh and I didn't know that div's didn't  have .value - thanks. This is my first week of JS/JQ so I am still making silly mistakes.

Comment: @JoseBazBaz, you probably didn't select it, it's the default.